# Error calling signout after gapi.auth.authorize

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm using client side login for google+. The access token expires in 1 hour. Calling `gapi.auth.signOut()` does not log the user out after the token has expired. I'm trying to re-authorise the user if his token has expired by calling `gapi.auth.authorize` with client_id, scope and `immediate = true` parameters. After calling this method, `gapi.auth.signOut()` doesn't work. I am not able to understand why is it.

Here is the code:

```
var google = {
    signOut: function() {
        var token = gapi.auth.getToken();

        if(!token) {
            var params = {
                'client_id': global.clientid,
                'session_state': global.sessionState,
                'response_type':'token'
            }
            gapi.auth.checkSessionState(params, function(state){
                if(state == true) {
                    google.doSignOut();
                } else {
                    google.silentAuthorize(function(data){
                        google.doSignOut();
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            google.doSignOut();
        }

    },

    doSignOut: function() {
        gapi.auth.signOut();
        google.loggedin = false;
    },

    silentAuthorize: function(callback) {
        var params = {};
        params.client_id = global.clientid;
        params.immediate = true;
        params.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"

        gapi.auth.authorize(params, callback);
    }
}
```

calling google.signOut works fine while the token hasn't expired. But once the token has expired or I simple call google.silentAuthorize() with a callback, calling gapi.auth.signOut() starts throwing an error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of null**

Been trying to figure this out for 4 hours now, any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anyway to renew token from front end, so I switched to hybrid method of using google auth. I now revive the session every time it is about to expire within php.